# Django-python- TestCase - transactions should never have a timestamp in the Future

Tags: python, django, django-testing, testcase, django-tests

I am working on a payment system that is registering transactions and timestamps. I would like to make a test to ensure that transactions are only made on a past date - it should not be possible to have a transaction with a future date.

models.py

```
 20  class Ledger(models.Model):
 19     account     = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 18     transaction = models.ForeignKey(UID, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
 17     amount      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
 16     timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
 15     text        = models.TextField()
 14
 13     @classmethod
 12     def transfer(cls, amount, debit_account, debit_text, credit_account, credit_text,                   is_loan=False) -> int:
 11         assert amount >= 0, 'Negative amount not allowed for transfer.'
 10         with transaction.atomic():
  9             if debit_account.balance >= amount or is_loan:
  8                 uid = UID.uid
  7                 cls(amount=-amount, transaction=uid, account=debit_account, text=debit_text).save()
  6                 cls(amount=amount, transaction=uid, account=credit_account, text=credit_text).save()
  5             else:
  4                 raise InsufficientFunds
  3         return uid
  2
  1     def __str__(self):
122         return f'{self.amount} :: {self.transaction} :: {self.timestamp} :: {self.account} :: {self.    text}'
```

I honestly don't even know where to start testing this class because Testing is very new to me. I have tested some things I saw online close to the below, but cannot see anything happening. Does it make any sense? Maybe there is something that makes more sense testing here instead... Suggestions are more than welcome!

tests.py

```
 class LedgerModelTestCase(TestCase):
        # def setUp(self):
  1     # no data to test yet
  2     def transfer_completed(self):
  3         time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
  4         print(time)
  5         future_transfer = Ledger(timestamp=time)
  6         print(future_transfer)
  7         self.assertIs(future_transfer.was_published_recently(), False)
  8
```

Comment: When `auto_now_add=True` is passed the current datetime is __always__ used and even if you pass a value it will be ignored, is this the behaviour you want to test or do you wish to be able to pass values to this field?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the current datetime and that is expected. I am working on a project where I HAVE to create custom tests for models and views.
I guess my issue is much more about trying to find out what/when to test. Currently, I am just trying to write a test for the fun, to have it, but everything I think of seems to unnecessary, as the timezone you pointed out :(